# How to scrape link and text of webpages using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest, stringr

I am trying to scrape speeches of Argentina's presidents using `rvest` in `R`. Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url_president <- "https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/discursos?page=%d"

# extract relevant data on webpage
map_df(1:2, function(i) {
  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_president, i))
  data.frame(
    title = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".category-item-title h3")) %>%
      str_trim(),
    date = html_text(html_nodes(pg, "time")),
    link = html_elements(pg, css = ".category-item-title h3") %>% html_attr('href'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
}) -> argentina_speeches_pres
```

This captures the title and date of the speeches but not the link (which I want to use to scrape the text). Could someone help me out with this? I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different css selector to get the links. Try -

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url_president <- sprintf("https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/discursos?page=%d", 1:2)

map_df(url_president, function(i) {
  pg <- read_html(i)
  tibble(
    title = html_nodes(pg, ".category-item-title h3") %>% html_text() %>%  str_trim(),
    date = html_nodes(pg, "time") %>% html_text() %>% str_trim(),
    link = html_elements(pg, 'a.panel') %>% 
      html_attr('href') %>% 
      paste0('https://www.casarosada.gob.ar', .),
  )
  
}) -> argentina_speeches_pres

argentina_speeches_pres

# A tibble: 80 x 3
#   title                                         date            link                                        
#   <chr>                                         <chr>           <chr>                                       
# 1 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Jueves 11 de N… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 2 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Viernes 05 de … https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 3 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Viernes 05 de … https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 4 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Jueves 04 de N… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 5 PALABRAS DEL PRESIDENTE DE LA NACIÓN, ALBERT… Miércoles 03 d… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 6 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Martes 02 de N… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 7 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Miércoles 27 d… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 8 Palabras del Presidente de la Nación, Albert… Miércoles 27 d… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# 9 Palabras del presidente de la Nación, Albert… Miércoles 20 d… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
#10 Palabras del presidente de la nación, Albert… Miércoles 20 d… https://www.casarosada.gob.ar/informacion/d…
# … with 70 more rows
```